# C reverse a string not working

Tags: c, string, reverse

Could someone look over this code and check if it should work or not

Its supposed to reverse an entered string (for example "hello" should become "olleh")

```
void stringReverse (char string1[])
{

    int length, i, j, k;
    char tmp;

    length = strlen(string1);
    j = length - 1;
    printf("Length: %i",length);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        tmp = string1[j];
        string1[j] = string1[i];
        string1[i] = tmp;
        j--;
    }
}
```

Comment: `look over this code and check if it should work or not` - Did you try runnning it? Your title implies you did and it doesn't work, what output are you getting? Did you use a debugger to step through the code?

Comment: It is reversing the string, you're just reversing it back.

Comment: `i < length` --> `i < j`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is working exactly as you told it to work. Your cycle must be up to `length/2` and not `length`.

Comment: reverse and repeat = nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* strrev(char* s)  {  
  char* h = s;    
  char* t = s; 
  char ch;  `
  while(*t++){};  
  t -= 2; 
  while(h < t){  
    ch = *h;  
    *h++ = *t;    /* h向尾部移动 */  
    *t-- = ch;    /* t向头部移动 */  
  }
  return(s);
}
```

function: `strrev`. This is implementation.

Hope this could help you.